# Error invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'double')

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm learning C++ right now. I'm confused about the below code. There is always this error showing up. Could someone can explain this problem to me, please?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PI 3.1415926;

int main()
{

//Declare variables
double radius;
double area;

//Input the radius
cout << "Enter the radius: ";
cin >> radius;

//Compute the area
area = PI * radius * radius ;

cout << "Area of Circle: " << area << endl;

return 0;}
```

And, when I switch the PI to the end of the calculating function, the code works.

Comment: Get rid of the `;` at the end of `#define`

Comment: Your code is expanding to `area = 3.1415926; * radius * radius;`